# What might "knock me over with a feather" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions

I recently received a text message which read: "well, knock me over with a feather!" It was in response to a statement which may or may not have been surprising (I honestly have no idea).

Has anyone heard this expression before? I am curious about what it was meant to express.

Comment: I haven't heard this expression for a long, long time.  It used to be something a Jewish grandmother would say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Knock me over with a feather" does indicate surprise.

See: [You could have knocked me over with a feather](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/You+could+have+knocked+me+over+with+a+feather)

The meaning is from the idea that surprise will put you off balance and so it will be easy to knock you over. In this case, so off balance that all it would take would be the brush of a feather.

Comment: It could also be used sarcastically to indicate that you are not surprized.

Comment: Anything can be used sarcastically to indicate the opposite, that's what sarcasm means.